# Flask with NGINX proxy_pass

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have a python flask server running on localhost:5000

I want NGINX to forward `www.example.com/app/rest` to `localhost:5000/rest`

Problem is, flask's url_for links will bypass any configuration, for example, I may have this button :

```
<a href="/rest">Rest</a>
```

Which will them route the browser to `www.example.com/rest`, which maps to nothing.

How can I fix this? From my understanding just changing nxing conf isn't enough, I also need to change something in Flask

My NGINX conf is as follows :

```
location /deploy/ {

      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
location /app/rest/ { # the trailing slash at the end is important

      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/rest;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

}

location /deploy/ {

      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

}
...
location / { # always be placed at the end
      ...
}
```